# Creating an object within the ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been writing a script for work and thought I would be really clever by doing something like this:

```
var signRenderer;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/***.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data: { 
            id: photoArray[curImg].id,
        },
        success: function(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
            data = data.data;
            signRenderer = new SignRenderer({
                sign: $('.sign-render'),
                signId: photoArray[curImg].id,
                form: $('.input-form'),
                north: new Sign({
                    id: data.N.id,
                    signId: photoArray[curImg].id,
                    isOn: data.N.visible,
                    disabled: data.N.disabled,
                    position: 'n',
                    direction: data.N.direction,
                    restriction: data.N.restriction,
                    periods: data.N.periods,
                    subtitle: data.N.subtitle,
                    footer: data.N.footer,
                }), ...
        });
```

The issue is that when I try and do anything the the `north` object using a function defined within `signRenderer`, it tells me that all of the properties of `north` are `undefined`.

A brief example of code use for the `SignRenderer` object:

```
function SignRenderer(options) {
    //Class Variables
        // ParkingSign Objects
    var signs = {
        n: options.north,
    }

    console.log(signs.n.getRestriction()); //undefined

}
```

And the `Sign` object (simplified):

```
function Sign (options) {
    var restriction = options.restriction;
    this.getRestriction = function () {
        return restriction;
    }
}
```

What I think is happening is that after the `success` function is finished, the `Sign` object `north` ceases to exist, and since passing objects into a function merely passes a reference, all of the values become `undefined` when I try to call functions within the `SignRenderer` object. Am I right in this assessment?

If this is the case, is there a neat way to address this? I didn't really want the `Sign` objects just hanging around as global variables, but if it has to be, it has to be.

Thanks guys.

Comment: It's not clear whether the code you provided does work but you are not sure whether it's the right way, or whether there's a problem with it. As you declare the `signRenderer` variable outside of the callback, it should already be available after the callback.

Comment: Sorry. There is a problem. All of the properties of `north` are undefined when I call for them from within functions of the `signRenderer` object. Could this maybe be an asynchronous issue, instead? But (the way I am seeing it) the script can't call functions from within `signRenderer` until I have made it within the `success` function.

Comment: You need to show us how you use the properties from within signRenderer object, it is not clear how you are using the parameters.

Comment: My guess is you are using signRenderer before the Ajax call is complete. Where are you using it?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the signRenderer class... Could also be a scope issue... Would also be great to have a fully working example, it would make trying to help you much easier! :)

Comment: I have expanded a little more to show when the issue occurs. So that `console.log` will return `undefined`. I thought this would be simply an issue in the first part of code, didn't realise I would need all of the detail. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I found the issue and it was totally unrelated to what was above. I was setting the values of a couple of variables to functions that didn't return anything.
Like: `variable = function(input);` but that function returned nothing! I hate it when stuff like this happens!

Comment: OK great, I thought the code above should work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Sign object, not SignRenderer.

```
function Sign (options) {
this.getRestriction = function () {
    return options.restriction;
}
```

}

Comment: I have expanded my original question now to include some of the SignRenderer class definition. I think my current syntax is correct.

Comment: I feel like such as ass to you right now, because you are being so helpful, but I am not being helpful to you. I have updated the `Sign` object again just to show you how I did it. Which should be functionally the same as what you wrote above. It still gives me `undefined`.

Comment: I am sorry! I found the issue and it was totally unrelated to what was above. I was setting the values of a couple of variables to functions that didn't return anything. Like: `variable = function(input);` but that function returned nothing! I hate it when stuff like this happens! I hate wasting generous coders time =(